# How to filter an array of objects where their values could contain null?

Tags: javascript

This is an example of an api response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Medicine1",
        "status": true,
        "location": "E1-2",
        "genericName": "Medicine1 Generic name",
        "laboratory": {
            "id": null,
            "name": null
        },
        "presentation": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tabletas"
        },
        "measure": {
            "id": 1,
            "unit": "Gramos",
            "abbreviation": "g"
        },
        "quantity": 25,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Medicine2",
        "status": true,
        "location": "E1-5",
        "genericName": "Medicine2 Generic",
        "laboratory": {
            "id": null,
            "name": null
        },
        "presentation": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Cremas"
        },
        "measure": {
            "id": 1,
            "unit": "Gramos",
            "abbreviation": "g"
        },
        "quantity": 500,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Medicine3",
        "status": true,
        "location": "E1-2",
        "genericName": null,
        "laboratory": {
            "id": null,
            "name": null
        },
        "presentation": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Unguentos"
        },
        "measure": {
            "id": 3,
            "unit": "Libras",
            "abbreviation": "lb"
        },
        "quantity": 5,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Medicine4",
        "status": true,
        "location": "E5-1",
        "genericName": null,
        "laboratory": {
            "id": null,
            "name": null
        },
        "presentation": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tabletas"
        },
        "measure": {
            "id": 2,
            "unit": "Kilogramos",
            "abbreviation": "kg"
        },
        "quantity": 5,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Medicine5",
        "status": true,
        "location": "E1-1",
        "genericName": null,
        "laboratory": {
            "id": null,
            "name": null
        },
        "presentation": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tabletas"
        },
        "measure": {
            "id": 1,
            "unit": "Gramos",
            "abbreviation": "g"
        },
        "quantity": 5,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Medicine5",
        "status": true,
        "location": "E1-1",
        "genericName": null,
        "laboratory": {
            "id": null,
            "name": null
        },
        "presentation": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tabletas"
        },
        "measure": {
            "id": 1,
            "unit": "Gramos",
            "abbreviation": "g"
        },
        "quantity": 5,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Medicine6",
        "status": true,
        "location": "E1-1",
        "genericName": null,
        "laboratory": {
            "id": null,
            "name": null
        },
        "presentation": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tabletas"
        },
        "measure": {
            "id": 1,
            "unit": "Gramos",
            "abbreviation": "g"
        },
        "quantity": 5,
        "percentage": null
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Medicine7",
        "status": true,
        "location": "E1-1",
        "genericName": null,
        "laboratory": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Falcon"
        },
        "presentation": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Gotas"
        },
        "measure": {
            "id": 1,
            "unit": "Gramos",
            "abbreviation": "g"
        },
        "quantity": 5,
        "percentage": null
    }
]
```

As you can see, the laboratory, percentage and genericName keys can have null value.

I need to filter this response according to a criteria that should be compared with each value

Here is the filter code

```
const criteria = 'some text';

fetchResource('medicines').then(medicines => {
    const results = medicines.filter(medicine => {
        return (
            medicine.name.toLowerCase().includes(criteria) ||
            medicine.genericName.toLowerCase().includes(criteria) ||
            medicine.presentation.name
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(criteria) ||
            medicine.measure.unit.toLowerCase().includes(criteria) ||
            medicine.measure.abbreviation
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(criteria) ||
            medicine.location.toLowerCase().includes(criteria)
        );
    });

    const helper = makeHelper();

    helper.render(results);
});
```

In backend, I thought about excluding the mentioned keys from the response when they do not have values. I have not tried yet but I understand that would work

I appreciate your advice on how to deal with this case on the client's side

Comment: Can you clarify, in words, what the filter criteria is?

Comment: How about adding `(medicine.location != null && medicine.location.toLowerCase().includes(....))`

Comment: Schokokuchen Bäcker your comment looks like a very smart solution, trying...

Comment: What is the expecte result?

Comment: The results must be a set of medicines where the value of any of its properties matches the criteria. The criteria is obtained from characters that the user inserts through an input

Comment: Schokokuchen Bäcker comment reminded me of an issue addressed in the https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator in the react documentation. Specifically where they comment on the following `true && expression always evaluates to expression`

Comment: So to clarify, this question is just about making sure `x` isn't `null` before calling `x.toLowerCase()`?

Answer (score 3):

There are other answers here that suggest using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the entire object to a string, but that's not a great solution. It would make it impossible to search for `generic`, because every object has a property named `genericName`. There is another way to use `stringify` that's a bit more graceful, and that's to take advantage of the `replacer` callback.

For example:

```
const results = medicines.filter(m => {
  var isMatch = false;
  JSON.stringify(m, (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "string" && value.toLowerCase().includes(criteria)) {
      isMatch = true;
    }
    return value;
  });
  return isMatch;
});
```

`results` will contain only those entries from `medicines` that contain some *value* that is a string that matches the given filter. You can extend this logic to include numeric values, such as `id`, or exclude certain keys you're not interested in, such as `abbreviation`.

Here's a quick demo implementing some more advanced logic. You'll of course want to tweak it to suit your exact needs:

```js
const medicines = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Medicine1",
    "status": true,
    "location": "E1-2",
    "genericName": "Medicine1 Generic name",
    "laboratory": { "id": null, "name": null },
    "presentation": { "id": 1, "name": "Tabletas" },
    "measure": { "id": 1, "unit": "Gramos", "abbreviation": "g" },
    "quantity": 25,
    "percentage": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Medicine2",
    "status": true,
    "location": "E1-5",
    "genericName": "Medicine2 Generic",
    "laboratory": { "id": null, "name": null },
    "presentation": { "id": 2, "name": "Cremas" },
    "measure": { "id": 1, "unit": "Gramos", "abbreviation": "g" },
    "quantity": 500,
    "percentage": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Medicine3",
    "status": true,
    "location": "E1-2",
    "genericName": null,
    "laboratory": { "id": null, "name": null },
    "presentation": { "id": 3, "name": "Unguentos" },
    "measure": { "id": 3, "unit": "Libras", "abbreviation": "lb" },
    "quantity": 5,
    "percentage": null
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Medicine4",
    "status": true,
    "location": "E5-1",
    "genericName": null,
    "laboratory": { "id": null, "name": null },
    "presentation": { "id": 1, "name": "Tabletas" },
    "measure": { "id": 2, "unit": "Kilogramos", "abbreviation": "kg" },
    "quantity": 5,
    "percentage": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Medicine5",
    "status": true,
    "location": "E1-1",
    "genericName": null,
    "laboratory": { "id": null, "name": null },
    "presentation": { "id": 1, "name": "Tabletas" },
    "measure": { "id": 1, "unit": "Gramos", "abbreviation": "g" },
    "quantity": 5,
    "percentage": null
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Medicine5",
    "status": true,
    "location": "E1-1",
    "genericName": null,
    "laboratory": { "id": null, "name": null },
    "presentation": { "id": 1, "name": "Tabletas" },
    "measure": { "id": 1, "unit": "Gramos", "abbreviation": "g" },
    "quantity": 5,
    "percentage": null
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Medicine6",
    "status": true,
    "location": "E1-1",
    "genericName": null,
    "laboratory": { "id": null, "name": null },
    "presentation": { "id": 1, "name": "Tabletas" },
    "measure": { "id": 1, "unit": "Gramos", "abbreviation": "g" },
    "quantity": 5,
    "percentage": null
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Medicine7",
    "status": true,
    "location": "E1-1",
    "genericName": null,
    "laboratory": { "id": 3, "name": "Falcon" },
    "presentation": { "id": 4, "name": "Gotas" },
    "measure": { "id": 1, "unit": "Gramos", "abbreviation": "g" },
    "quantity": 5,
    "percentage": null
  }
];

const btn = document.getElementById("go");
const inp = document.getElementById("search");
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const criteria = inp.value.toLowerCase();
  const results = medicines.filter(m => {
    var isMatch = false;
    JSON.stringify(m, (key, value) => {
      // Search 'id' values
      if (key === "id" && value !== null && value.toString().includes(criteria)) {
        isMatch = true;
        // Ignore 'abbreviation'
      } else if (key !== "abbreviation") {
        // Search all other string values
        if (typeof value === "string" && value.toLowerCase().includes(criteria)) {
          isMatch = true;
        }
      }

      return value;
    });
    return isMatch;
  });
  console.log(results);
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="search" placeholder="filter" /><button id="go">Go</button><br>
<code>
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer. I would just add that you should probably `toString()` value and add `typeof(value) == 'int'` to  typecheck since OP says they have to be searched as well.

Comment: @jmkmay Good catch. I've updated the answer to demonstrate a bit more advanced logic.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code will error on `medicine.genericName.toLowerCase()` if the `genericName` field isn't a string. To avoid that you could try one of the following instead:

Fall back to a default:
`(medicine.genericName || '').toLowerCase().includes(criteria)`

Check the value first:
`(medicine.genericName && medicine.genericName.toLowerCase().includes(criteria))`

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit tough to figure out what you're trying to do with the example, but I'm assuming you want to check if the value of multiple keys in your API response contains a substring criteria?

If that's the case, you could try something like:

```
fetchResource('medicines').then(medicines => {
    const results = medicines.filter(medicine => {
        for (var key in medicine){
            if((typeof(medicine[key] == 'string' || typeof(medicine[key] == 'int') && medicine[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(criteria)){
                return true
            }
            else if(typeof(medicine[key]) === 'object'){
                for(var subkey in medicine[key]){
                    if((typeof(medicine[key][subkey]) == 'string' || typeof(medicine[key][subkey]) === 'int') && medicine[key][subkey].toString().toLowerCase().includes(criteria)){
                        return true
                    }
                }          
            }
        }
        return false
    })
})
```

This is obviously much cleaner than hard coding all of the property names.

Comment: nice solution but in this case there are keys whose values are objects and one is a number

Comment: Ah. Missed that part. You can call toString() on each element then. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I told before, use a forEach in your array; following a function to filter;
Use JSON.stringify so you que see all properties in row;
Apply a pattern as criteria

```js
var yourCriteria = ""; // or any Regex
var yourArray = [];
var newArray = []; 
yourArray.forEach(function(e){
 if (JSON.stringify(e).toLowerCase().indexOf(yourCriteria) < 0) 
     newArray.push(e);
})
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `criteria` is a substring not the value. Also the array contains a list of objects, not strings.

Comment: @jmkmay your code above doesnt answer when you have more sublevels =D